# Does Groovy have support for something like Ruby Modules?

Tags: ruby, groovy, mixins, dynamic-languages

[Ruby modules](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm) make things like passing a [database connection or other dependencies](http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/) to various objects much easier while allowing for separation of concerns.  Does Groovy support a similar functionality?  And if so what is it called?

Comment: Groovy has [Extension Modules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module) but I don't know enough Ruby to know if they're analagous

Comment: They look like [Singletons](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/groovy-goodness-create-singleton-class.html) to me

Comment: @WillP I'll give you that...but they're alot easier to wire up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby modules are used either as mixins or to namespace a class (e.g. `Net::HTTP`).

To mixin the behavior you can use @mixin annotation. like examples here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations.

To namespace, groovy uses same mechanism as java i.e. using packages (e.g. `groovy.sql.Sql`).

I am not sure if that answered your question or not. But for dependency injection, while its common to do it mixin way in ruby (or even in scala/play), I have not seen it done a lot using `@mixin` in groovy. Usually a DI container like spring is used.

Comment: The argument in the article above (http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/) is that DI is clunky compared to Ruby modules...but if that's indeed true, then the only real difference I can see is that you can't do AOP in Ruby using a Module/Mixin (well and that's only true as to my limited knowledge of Ruby in this area...so it may actually be possible).

Comment: Yeah that looks like the same sort of functionality, it's a tiny bit more complex but not much looks good.